# Security Proof of Short Schnorr Signature

Tags: provable-security, schnorr-signature

I know that this is a very specific question, but I still hope that someone can help me. I'm trying to understand the security of the short schnorr signature a little bit better. The security parameter is $k$. The Schnorr Signature $\sigma = (s,e)$ with $s,e \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ has a signature length of $4k$ bits ($s$ and $e$ have $2k$ bits, $e$ is a hash output). The Short Schnorr Signature uses a shorter hash output of $k$ bit length so that the resulting signature has a length of $3k$ bits. Apparently, the Short Schnorr Signature has the same security level as the "normal" Schnorr Signature. As stated in the security proofs on the last page of the paper ['Security of Signed ElGamal Encryption', Schnorr, Jakobsson (page 85)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44448-3_7). I'm just going to cite the part that I don't understand and hope that someone can explain it to me without me having to give more context.

> ... a CCA-attacker does not succeed better than with probability
> $\frac{1}{2}+t^2/q+l(2^{-k}-\frac{1}{q})$, where $l$ is the number of
> decryptor interactions. This shows that random hash values can
> securely range over a set of $\sqrt q$ values.

( $q \approx 2^{2k}$ )

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's surprising in the quote is that the result invoked (from Theorem 1), the "CCA-attacker", and the "decryptor", are for encryption, not signature. I admit I fail to make sense out of that. I do get that $k$ is supposed to be the width of the hash in short Schnorr signature.

Comment: Is the question about this specific paper? Is it restricted to theoretical (s)EUF-CMA, or do other security aspects count? Short Schnorr signature has a number of borderline pratical issues that normal Schnorr, EdDSA, (EC)DSA do not have, including: vulnerability to second pre-image attack of the hash with effort $2^k$ hashes (meaning the symmetric hash, not the asymmetric crypto, is the practical weak spot); and that the private key holder can make pairs of meaningful messages with the same signature at cost about $2^{k/2}$ hashes (which can be perceived as a repudiation/FUD risk).

Comment: Well, security of short Schnorr sigs is proven in completely another paper -  neven.org/papers/schnorr.html . Please look into this first